# Syntax error with (old?) open folder command

Tags: applescript

I'm working my way through *AppleScript 1-2-3* (2009) and can't seem to run this example:

```
tell application "Finder" 
    close every window
    open home
    set toolbar visible of the front Finder window to true
    set the sidebar width of the front Finder window to 135
    set the current view of the front Finder window to column view
    set the bounds of the front Finder window to {36, 116, 511, 674}
    set folder "Documents" of home
    set toolbar visible of the front Finder window to false
    set the current view of the front Finder window to flow view
    set the bounds of front Finder window to {528, 116, 1016, 674}
    select the last finder window
end tell
```

The parser chokes on the `set folder` command, telling me "A end of line can’t go after this property."  Unless I've screwed up (entirely possible), or the book is just wrong, the language must have changed since 2009. If so, how?

Update: the answers and comments (worth reading!) convince me that the books is just wrong.

Comment: The primary reason the `set folder "Documents" of home` line of code, from your question, errors out is because it's not syntactically correct! Have a look at the [`set`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW52) _command_ in the AppleScript Language Guide for its syntax and examples!

Comment: I'm sure you're right, but telling me to look and the Language Guide isn't helpful. I've been studying Applescript for about 15 minutes; referring to the language guide in my current state of ignorance would would be sort of like a confused ESL student thumbing through the Oxford English Grammar! Sucks that an "Apple Certified" book contains such a basic error. And in the first 39 pages!

Comment: Oh, FFS. I can accept that some people might think this is  bad question. But downvoting it without explaining why is just childish.

Comment: In response to your comment “telling me to look and the Language Guide isn't helpful”, I think the advice that @user3439894 steered you towards (look and the Language Guide), was “dead on” appropriate.  Speaking for myself only (but I am sure others would agree), Learning AppleScript has been a process of exactly that.. Reading language guides, and examples, over and over and over again (even if it seemed like I was reading Japanese)

Comment: I think your comment misses the point. I might well end up following your advice (especially if I run into more stupid mistakes) but right now I'm trying to read *this* book. Your advice comes down to "throw out that stupid book and just read the language manual." Which might well be good advice, but doesn't help me with the task at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question of how AppleScript might have changed since 2009, I won't try and guess the myriad ways it could have evolved since then (and I couldn't find language documentation from 2009 or before), but I can highlight the current formulation as it pertains to your code snippet.  Namely, where your script is throwing the error, with the syntax error in `set folder "Documents" of home`.

The way the `set` command is defined in (the current version of) AppleScript is:

> [for the] **assign**[ment of] **one or more values to one or more variables**.

It has the following syntax:

> **set** *variablePattern* **to** *expression*

where `variablePattern` is the name of a variable or list of variables, and `expression` evaluates to the value(s) that will be assigned to the variable(s).

(Note: The [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW52) states that the latter half of the declaration, i.e. `to %expression%`, is optional.  However, I cannot think of an instance for which this is true, and, as far as I know, `set` must **always** follow the complete syntax as outlined above.  Perhaps this is one of the ways the language has changed...?)

So, put simply, `set` is always used to **take the value of one thing** and **assign it to another**, just like all the other lines of your code snippet do.

In the following line:

```
    set folder "Documents" of home
```

we have only half a declaration: the command starts by providing an object (a folder, in this case) that is looking to take on a new value, but then doesn't go on to state what that new value ought to be.

Moreover, the `folder` object isn't typically one that can be assigned values itself.  One cannot command:

```
    set folder "Documents" of home to desktop
```

However, one *can* assign the `folder` object to something else, such as a variable or the value of an existing property, like the `target` property of a `Finder window`:

```
    set the target of the front Finder window to folder "Documents" of home
```

The `set` command is instructing the AppleScript to use the value of the expression `folder "Document" of home` (which evaluates to a location reference on the hard drive) and assign it to the `target` property of the `front Finder window` (which controls which directory is shown in the window).  As you'd expect, this causes the directory of the active *Finder* window to switch from the **Home** directory to the **Documents** directory.

This seems like an unlikely desired outcome, as applying all of these actions to a single *Finder* window means that the preceding lines are somewhat superfluous: there would be no need to open the *Home* folder and set its properties (`toolbar visible`, `sidebar width`, `current view` and `bounds`), only then to change directory and set all of these properties to new values.

So I think the most likely solution is one hinted at by [@wch1zpink](https://superuser.com/users/674547/wch1zpink) in his answer, which is to open a new *Finder* window at the location of the *Documents* folder.

I chose to do this like in exactly the same way the script did so with the *Home* folder:

```
    open folder "Documents" of home
```

which replaces the problem line completely.  So the resulting script has a pleasing symmetry in the way the two windows are created and manipulated:

```
    tell application "Finder"
        activate
        close every window

        open home
        set toolbar visible of the front Finder window to true
        set the sidebar width of the front Finder window to 135
        set the current view of the front Finder window to column view
        set the bounds of the front Finder window to {36, 116, 511, 674}

        open folder "Documents" of home
        set toolbar visible of the front Finder window to false
        set the current view of the front Finder window to flow view
        set the bounds of front Finder window to {528, 116, 1016, 674}

        select the last Finder window
    end tell
```

The `open` command, obviously, opens a new *Finder* window at the specified location, but also makes that new *Finder* window the **front *Finder* window**.

From this, it's easier to see that the first block of `set` statements are for one *Finder* window; and the second block are for another.

Hopefully, I've addressed your query directly and provided an explanation that makes sense.  Forgive me if any of what I've written sounds patronising: I tried to avoid assuming what you do and don't know about AppleScript, despite evidence that you're clearly no novice (2.5K reputation on Super User).  On the other hand, if any of what I've written is ambiguous or poorly explained, let me know, and I'll happily clarify or re-word as appropriate.

Comment: Regarding your "Note: The AppleScript Language Guide states ...", I assume that in context, _expression_ is optional in that it can also be set to `""`, which Apple might not consider as an expression, since `""` is literally nothing but it does initialize the _variable_, which has its uses. It's either something like that or bad documentation, which only Apple can address if it's the latter.

Comment: Thank you, that precisely answers my question. (Perhaps in more detail than I needed, but there's no harm in that.) You make me suspect that this isn't a change in the language but a simple mistake plus a failure to to check the example by actually running it. Kinda makes me wonder how well QA'd the book is.

Answer (score -1):

If your intention with this line of code...  `set folder "Documents" of home` Is to have the current finder window displaying the "Documents" folder, then simply replace this line `set folder "Documents" of home` with this...

```
set theFolder to folder "Documents" of home
open theFolder
```

Comment: My intention is as stated: find out why I'm getting a syntax error.